# Pytorch TypeError: eq() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: numpy, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

```
num_samples = 10
def predict(x):
    sampled_models = [guide(None, None) for _ in range(num_samples)]
    yhats = [model(x).data for model in sampled_models]
    mean = torch.mean(torch.stack(yhats), 0)
    return np.argmax(mean.numpy(), axis=1)

print('Prediction when network is forced to predict')
correct = 0
total = 0
for j, data in enumerate(test_loader):
    images, labels = data
    predicted = predict(images.view(-1,28*28))
    total += labels.size(0)
    correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
print("accuracy: %d %%" % (100 * correct / total))
```

**Error**:

> ```
> correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item() TypeError: 
> eq() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (numpy.ndarray), but expected one of:  
> * (Tensor other)
>   didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!numpy.ndarray!)
> * (Number other)
>   didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!numpy.ndarray!)
> ```

*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to compare `predicted` and `labels`. However, your `predicted` is an `np.array` while `labels` is a `torch.tensor` therefore `eq()` (the `==` operator) cannot compare between them.
Replace the `np.argmax` with [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html#torch.argmax):

```
 return torch.argmax(mean, dim=1)
```

And you should be okay.