# Invalid combination of arguments - eq()

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm using a code shared [here](https://gist.github.com/johnolafenwa/96b3322aabb61d4d36fd870a77f02aa3) to test a CNN image classifier. When I call the test function, I got this error on [line 155](https://gist.github.com/johnolafenwa/96b3322aabb61d4d36fd870a77f02aa3#file-simplenet-py-L155):

```
test_acc += torch.sum(prediction == labels.data)
TypeError: eq() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (numpy.ndarray), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: ([31;1mnumpy.ndarray[0m)
 * (Number other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: ([31;1mnumpy.ndarray[0m)
```

Fragment of the `test` function:

```
def test():
    model.eval()
    test_acc = 0.0
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_loader):

        if cuda_avail:
                images = Variable(images.cuda())
                labels = Variable(labels.cuda())

        #Predict classes using images from the test set
        outputs = model(images)
        _,prediction = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        prediction = prediction.cpu().numpy()
        test_acc += torch.sum(prediction == labels.data) #line 155



    #Compute the average acc and loss over all 10000 test images
    test_acc = test_acc / 10000

return test_acc
```

After a quick search I see that the error is probably related to the comparison between the `prediction` and `labels`, as seem in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999926/pytorch-typeerror-eq-received-an-invalid-combination-of-arguments).

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `.numpy()` here `prediction = prediction.cpu().numpy()`?
That way you convert PyTorch tensor to NumPy array, making it incompatible type to compare with `labels.data`.

Removing `.numpy()` part should fix the issue.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you! I hope this helps someone in the future.